# Activate virtual environment and install requirements in the first setup automatically - Python, Windows

Tags: python, installation, python-venv, activation

I want to write a first_setup.py script, where users can run it for the first time and the script will do the entire setup automatically, namely it will create a virtual environment, activate it, and install the requirements with pip. Users can then start to use the program without worrying about any dependency issue.

Therefore, I used venv together with subprocess library. My Python version is 3.7.5. With the following command, it creates the virtual environment in the working directory:

```
env_name = ".venv"
subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "venv", env_name])
```

However, activation doesn't work. I tried to activate it in various ways, for example:

```
subprocess.run([f"{venv_name}\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1"], shell=True)
```

This just opens Activate.ps1 in Windows Text Editor like a .txt file (?). I also thought to add .../Scripts/python.exe to the PATH variable, but it didn't work actually.

Furthermore, when the venv created by the script, VS Code pops up a message saying a venv detected, do you want to use it? If I click on Yes, then it changes my interpreter to venv, which is exactly what I want to do, but automatically with the first_setup.py script.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Does this first_setup script need to be Python?

The problem is that the activate script sets environment variables for the shell, which is why it’s usually run with ‘source’.

Comment: I have classes/methods written in Python and calling them from the first_setup script. That's why, It's in Python.  Is source not for Unix systems? I am on Windows and according to venv doc, it should be activated  <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1. To be honest, I didn't understand why it opens the script in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

try using bash file:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install your_library
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do that in Python script, because I have setup functions there and thought to combine all things in a script. But I think it doesn't work like that. Creating venv, installing dependencies and calling python script from bash file works.